# Inverse of parametrized ellipse area

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

If you parametrize an ellipse (with the center, not a focus, at the origin) as:

`{a Cos[t], b Sin[t]}`

the area traced out from the focus (not origin) for a given $t$ is:

`a b t/2 - Sqrt[a^2-b^2] b Sin[t]/2`

(Note that $a$ and $b$ are the semimajor and semiminor axes and that I'm assuming $a > b$ without loss of generality.)

My question:  what's the inverse of this area function in terms of $t$?

In other words, what's:

```
  Solve[a b t/2 - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]  b Sin[t]/2 == x, t]
```

`Solve` won't give me an answer "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.", but I'm convinced there is one.

Given the number of ellipse-related functions that exist in *Mathematica*, surely some combination of these yields the inverse of my ellipse-related function?

Comment: Not clear how you get ( assuming $ \epsilon = c/a$) the transcendental equation $ ( 2 x /(ab)) =( t - \epsilon \sin t ) $ . Even if it is clear, the matter of solution with transcendental equations and elliptic integrals or their inverse elliptic functions are anyhow two different things. The area of a chord of the circle is not determined by elliptic integrals or functions.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be asking for the solution to Kepler's equation for the [eccentric anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly). That is, given the mean anomaly $x$, find the eccentric anomaly $t$, where $x=t-e*Sin[t]$, and $e$ is the eccentricity. There is no closed form solution.

You can use FindRoot in the following function to find `t` given `x`, `a`, and `b`.

```
FindtGiven[x_, a_, b_] := 
   t /. FindRoot[
                 a b t/2 - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2] b Sin[t]/2 == x,
                 {t, -2 x/(b (Sqrt[a^2 - b^2] - a))}]
```

The initial guess for `t` supplied to FindRoot is from the linear term in the series expansion.

```
Series[a b t/2 - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2] b Sin[t]/2, {t, 0, 3}]
```

Values of `t` look like the following.

```
With[{a = 1.5, b = 1.0},
   ListLinePlot[
      Table[{x, FindtGiven[x, a, b]}, {x, 0.1, 10, 0.1}],
      Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, 
      BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, GridLines -> Automatic]]
```

[image: eccentric anomaly]